# Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. Cant see anything wrong

Tags: python

I have this python code in my script.

```
dataBase = str(request.forms.get('db')) 
data =  "/usr/local/Calpont/mysql/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/usr/local/Calpont/mysql/my.cnf  -u root %s -e \"show tables like \'f_\%s\'\"" %(dataBase)
```

But its giving me the following error when I run it:-

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two* `%s` markers in your format string:

```
... -u root %s -e \"show tables like \'f_\%s\' ...
            ^^                            ^^
```

but only one argument, `database`.

You need to have enough arguments for the number of markers. Most likely, this is a simple matter of one of the following.

- If you are trying to use another parameter, you need to provide it, such as with `... % (dataBase, tableName)`.
- If you are trying to use the *literal* `%` mark, you need to escape it as `%%`, *not* `\%` as you may be thinking.

Given the fact you're using `like`, I consider the second the most likely possibility, as `%` is the wildcard for that operator.

The following transcripts may make the problem clearer:

```
pax> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> print "... -u root %s -e \"show tables like \'f_\%s\' ..." %("A")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

>>> print "... -u root %s -e \"show tables like \'f_\%s\' ..." %("A","B")
... -u root A -e "show tables like 'f_\B' ...

>>> print "... -u root %s -e \"show tables like \'f_%%\' ..." %("A")
... -u root A -e "show tables like 'f_%' ...

>>> _
```

The first and second commands shows that using two `%s` markers requires two arguments.

The third command shows how to properly escape `%` in the string.

Comment: I dont see the second %s - `"show tables like \'f_\%\'\"`. And the question was not edited.

Comment: The question _was_ edited, you just can't see it if it happens in the first four minutes.